# Retrieve list of all current environment variables

Tags: c++, c, qt, environment-variables

I'm looking for a possibility to get ALL environment variables that are set and valid for my running application.

To be more clear: I do NOT want get only the value of one known variable like it would be possible with getenv(), I do not know anything about existing variables and want to retrieve all of them.

Preferably I would like to do that in Qt but a solution that makes use of C++ or ANSI-C functions would be fine for me too.

Thanks!

**Update for these closing this question without understanding (or I guess even reading what I have asked): no, the question was NOT answered in the other thread as I**

**a) have asked for a Qt solution in first place**

**b) this thread gives a solution that does not work on all platforms!**

**Meanwhile I found it out for my own and without the "help" of these guys closing questions not because they understand the problem but because they are bored or whatever. The answer to my question is QProcess::systemEnvironment()**

Comment: ANSI-C? What year is this? (That's not a thing any more in any practical sense. It refers to C89, which is 31+ years old now.)

Comment: This depends on your OS. Consider [`getenv()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html) and friends if POSIX is an option.

Comment: "*set and valid for a running application*" Is that *your* application, or some other application that happens to be running on the same machine?

Comment: @dxiv you are right - yes, the own application is meant, no other application running somewhere

Answer (score 2):

The 3rd `char **envp` is totally nonstandard, it is not even mandated by POSIX.

The list of environment variables can be fetched *anywhere* from the [`environ`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/basedefs/xbd_chap08.html) variable in POSIX systems:

```
char **env = environ;
while (env) {
    printf("%s\n", *env++);
}
```

Additionally, the code using the 3rd argument of `main` could be reasonably expected to successfully compile on platforms that do not support the 3rd argument, and then you'll just have some garbage pointer and undefined behaviour, whereas a variable called `environ` declared with type `char **` is unlikely to be anything else besides the POSIX compatible one.

Answer (score 1):

The third argument of the function main is a list of environment variables, the list ends with nullptr.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv, char** env) {
  while (env)
    printf("%s\n", *env++);
}
```

Comment: You beat me to it. Everyone seems to forget about that 3rd param to `main`.

Comment: Tried this right now with Windows and get back only some crap there...